# Getting the total, average, maximum and minimum scores of a 3x4 matrix inside a 2 dimensional array in c programming

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem to get the total score, average score, max and minimum score. I can't find the problem on my program. I would like some help on my codes. All help is greatly appreciated. I'm using Dev-C++ as a software for my programs.
Anyway, my only problem is about the codes for the total score, maximum score and minimum score.

Here's my program:

```
int main(void)

  {

    char n[3]={'A','B','C'};
    int s[3][4]={90,50,100,10,60,100,20,50,80,70,100,75};
    double average=0;
    int x, y, total=0, max=0, min=0;

    for(x=0;x<3;x++)
    {
        printf("%c\t",n[x]);
        for(y=0;y<4;y++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",s[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(x=0;x<3;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<4;y++)
        {
           total+=s[x][y];
           average=(double)total/n[x];
        }
        printf("\nThe total score of %c is %d with the average score of
%.2lf",n[x],total,average);
    }
    max=s[0][0];
    for(x=0;x<3;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<4;y++)
        {
            if(s[x][y]>max)
            max=s[x][y];
        }
        printf("\nThe maximum score of %c is %d",n[x],max);
    }
    min=s[0][0];
    for(x=0;x<3;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<4;y++)
        {
            if(s[x][y]<min)
            min=s[x][y];
        }
        printf("\nThe minimum score of %c is %d",n[x],min);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

The result is:

```
A     90     50     100     10
B     60     100    20      50
C     80     70     100     75

The total score of A is 250 with the average score of 3.85
The total score of B is 480 with the average score of 7.27
The total score of C is 805 with the average score of 12.01
The maximum score of A is 100
The maximum score of B is 100
The maximum score of C is 100
The minimum score of A is 10
The minimum score of B is 10
The minimum score of C is 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't reset the min and max per row, only per matrix so it will reflect that.

Move the initialization inside the first for loop and it will work.

```
for(x=0;x<3;x++)
{
    max=s[x][0];
    ...
```

Also you have to set the total to zero every row and there is no need to calculate average inside the second loop, it should be calculated outside it since that will be the correct value.

Comment: I'll try to do what you suggested

Comment: same thing for the totals too

Comment: @PeteB Thanks, added that too

Comment: Could you please expound it? If you wouldn't mind

Comment: Expound it?  @SamiKuhmonen answer seems very clear to me, so I upvoted it as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Got the program running fit to the codes